# LibGDX - Collision detection between Player and a Platform (or tile) WITHOUT using TiledMap

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection, physics

In my game the character is constantly moving from left to right, so there will never be a situation where he hits the right side of a platform. I had a very brief talk with somebody and he suggested me to model my platform as 4 rectangles so that I would only need 3 cases in my algorithm (i.e. **Player** can only collide with the rectangles shaded green in the image below). Here's a visual description of what I mean:

[image]

I gave it a try but the collision detection is still messed up. It doesn't go through the side of the platform (this is good news since we want this to happen) but you can't glide on top of it or bounce under it. Can anyone see where I may have gone wrong?

```
public void checkCollisions(ArrayList<GameObject> list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            GameObject go1 = list.get(i);
            GameObject go2 = list.get(j);
            boolean playerPlatformCollision = go1.getType()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("player") && go2.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("platform");
            if (playerPlatformCollision) {
              Rectangle playerRect = go1.getRect();
              Rectangle platformRect = go2.getRect();
                if (playerRect.overlaps(platformRect)) {

                    float platformRectX, platformRectY, platformRectWidth, platformRectHeight;
                    platformRectX = go2.getRect().getX(); // x position of the platform
                    platformRectY = go2.getRect().getY(); // y position of the platform
                    platformRectWidth = go2.getRect().getWidth(); // width of platform
                    platformRectHeight = go2.getRect().getHeight(); // height of platform

                    Rectangle caseA = new Rectangle(platformRectX,
                            platformRectY, platformRectX + 1,
                            platformRectHeight);
                    Rectangle caseB = new Rectangle(platformRectX + 1,
                            (platformRectY + platformRectHeight) - 1,
                            platformRectWidth - 1, platformRectHeight);
                    Rectangle caseC = new Rectangle(platformRectX + 1,
                            platformRectY, platformRectWidth, 1);

                    if (playerRect.overlaps(caseA)) {
                        go1.setxSpeed(0);
                    } else if (playerRect.overlaps(caseB)) {
                        go1.setySpeed(0);
                    } else if (playerRect.overlaps(caseC)) {
                        go1.setySpeed(-3f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you are not clear with any parts of the code.

Comment: sorry for my English, but I'm not clear what the question, if I can clarify me, maybe I can help

Comment: If you take a look at my new edit it might make more sense. I am trying to implement mario-style collision detection between a Player and a Platform/Tile. The player can collide with the Platform in 3 different ways; by hitting the side of the Platform (case A in the picture), top of the platform or the bottom of the platform. When he touches case A I want the player to have 0 horizontal speed (so he doesn't go through the platform), when he touches case B I want him to have 0 vertical speed (so he doesn't fall through the platform) and case C: bounce down.

Comment: case A rectangle has width of 1 pixel. case B and C rectangles have height of 1 pixel

Comment: Yes, why widht/height just 1 pixel? How fast is your player moving. He can easily skip that pixel and end up in red area. Probably most accurate detection technique would be to store previous coordinates. So when player end's up into some tile you "draw" a line between current and previous player position and calculate intersection between that line and tile edges. Then you check what edge was intersected - top, left or right. A bit more complicated but may be more reliable.

Comment: You're right, maybe 1 pixel width/height is a bad idea. Do you know of any tutorials or guides that demonstrate the technique you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure that this is the issue, but it seems that this problem is not addressed in your code, and I have had similar problems myself when ignoring this. When your player collides with the platform, it means that its rectangle is already intersecting the platform, by anywhere between 1 and how fast you are going number of pixels. Just adjusting the x and y speed is not enough. You must also remove the player rectangle from the platform, or else the player will get stuck. This can be done by using a loop and checking if your player is still colliding. if so, move 1 pixel over in the direction you came from, until no longer colliding.